# How can I oscillate numbers in a list?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

Question: How can I make these oscillate as such that the first digits or expression is + the next is - the one after is + and so on and so forth for the lists provided below (without using a specially made function for oscillation if one even exists).

I'm currently getting output as shown below:

```
    x + x^3/6 + x^5/120 + x^7/5040 + x^9/362880  
1. {1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69,
73, 77, 81, 85, 89}
```

Expected output:

```
x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040 + x^9/362880  
2. {1, -5, 9, -13, 17, -21, 25, -29, 33, -37, 41, -45, 49, -53, 57, -61, 65, -69, 73, -77, 81, -85, 89}

Sum[x^j/Factorial[j], {j, 1, 9, 2}];
myOsc = Table[i, {i, 1, 89, 4}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small improvement that does not require the extra s variable:

```
MapIndexed[(-1)^(1 + #2[[1]])*#1 &, x + x^3/6 + x^5/120 + x^7/5040 + x^9/362880]
```

> x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040 + x^9/362880

Answer (score 1):

```
Sum[If[OddQ[(j - 1)/2], -x^j, x^j]/Factorial[j], {j, 1, 9, 2}]
```

> x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040 + x^9/362880

```
myOsc = Table[If[OddQ[(i - 1)/4], -i, i], {i, 1, 89, 4}]
```

> {1, -5, 9, -13, 17, -21, 25, -29, 33, -37, 41, -45, 49, -53, 57, -61, 65, -69, 73, -77, 81, -85, 89}

Answer (score 1):

```
s = -1; Map[(s *= -1) # &, x + x^3/6 + x^5/120 + x^7/5040 + x^9/362880]
```

> x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040 + x^9/362880

note of caution mathematica will put your expression in canonical order for you first. So for example if you key it in like this:

```
s = -1; Map[(s *= -1) # &,x^3/6 + x  + x^5/120 + x^7/5040 + x^9/362880]
```

you get the same result

> x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040 + x^9/362880